# How to export .TOL and .DRI files in ALTIUM designer 16

Tags: altium, gerber

Is possible to generate this files? my PCB provider asked it to me but I can't find them in gerber exportation tool.
Thanks

Comment: It's possible Altium outputs these files but just gives them a different name. Can you find out from the fab what these files are supposed to represent? For example, is .TOL for "TOLerance" or "TOp Layer"? (Top Layer in Altium would be the .GTL file)

Comment: TOL should be something related to CNC TOOLS list like drill drawing but with the information of what kind of tool to use.

Comment: @Elius94 In Altium there is not a designated layer for the tooling information. Instead you pick a mechanical layer and dedicate it for that purpose. Then just the mechanical layer to the Gerber export

Comment: If you're looking for the aperture file Altium provides it as a plain text report file. Not sure of the name off the top of my head.